# For printing to labels, shifting PDF to align with labels at print time?

Tags: printing

I'm printing to labels.  The source PDF is offset somewhat from the labels.  I can measure the offset... is there a way to nudge, scale or skew the printout to match up?

Answer (score 1):

I was just able to do this yesterday with pdfedit. What I cannot seem to figure out how to do yet though is to script this from the terminal.

In pdfedit, load the document. Click on the set page transformation matrix icon.

On the first tab, click on Translate (shift) page and set which pages you want to operate on.

On the Page translation (second) tab, set the x and/or y translation values.

Click OK.

All the best!